# __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) () segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, gdb

This is the backtrace:
[image]

The definition of SymbolStack (in Symbols.h):

```
#ifndef HW3_SYMBOLS_H
#define HW3_SYMBOLS_H

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include "shared_def.h"

using std::vector; using std::string;
extern int yylineno;

...

class SymbolStack {
public:
    vector<int> pos_stack = vector<int>();
    vector<SymbolTable*> scope_stack = vector<SymbolTable*>();
public:
    SymbolStack();
    ErrorType is_func_valid(const string& func_name, const string& retype, vector<string>* params_types, bool is_override);
    void push(bool is_while, Types retType = T_NONE);
    void pop();
    SymbolTable* get_curr_scope();
    void symbol_document(const string& symbol_name,const string& symbol_type, bool is_func = false,
                         bool is_over = false, vector<string>* func_params_types = nullptr); // add new symbol to the stack
    void func_param_document(const string& symbol_name, const string& symbol_type, int pos); // add new function to the stack
    bool symbol_exists(const string& symbol_name); // does a symbol exists?
    SymbolEntry* get_symbol(const string& symbol_name);
    SymbolEntry* get_func_symbol(const string& func_name, const string& retype, vector<string>* params_types, int* count); // if retype == "" error if count >= 2
   // bool function_exists(const string& name, vector<string>* params_types = nullptr);
    bool check_program();
    ~SymbolStack();
};

...

#endif //HW3_SYMBOLS_H
```

Types is an enum defined in shared_def.h.
The methods in Symbols.cpp:

```
SymbolStack::SymbolStack(){
    pos_stack.push_back(0); // init to offset = zero
    this->push(false, T_VOID);
    vector<string> print_param = vector<string>();
    vector<string> printi_param = vector<string>();
    print_param.push_back("string");
    printi_param.push_back("int");
    this->symbol_document("print", "void", FUNC, &print_param);
    this->symbol_document("printi", "void", FUNC, &printi_param);
}
void SymbolStack::push(bool is_while, Types retType){
    retType = retType == T_NONE? scope_stack.back()->ret_type : retType;
    SymbolTable* first_scope = new SymbolTable(pos_stack.back(), is_while, retType);
    pos_stack.push_back(pos_stack.back());
    scope_stack.push_back(first_scope);
}
```

The constructor of SymbolStack is called in parser.ypp:

```
%{
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include "types.h"
    #include "hw3_output.hpp"
    extern int yylineno;
    extern int yylex();
    int yyerror(const char* message);
    extern SymbolStack tables;
%}

definitions...
%%
Rule...
%%

tables = SymbolStack();
int main(){
        int res = yyparse();
        bool is_valid_program = tables.check_program();
        if(!is_valid_program){
            output::errorMainMissing();
            exit(0);
        }
        tables.pop();
        return res;
}
int yyerror(const char * message){
    output::errorSyn(yylineno);
    exit(0);
}
```

I didn't manage to debug it using gdb because it happens even before main is called. It also happens if I remove this line "this->push(false, T_VOID);" from the constructor.

EDIT: There is nothing in any source file I use that is defined as static.

Comment: @RichardCritten Thank you, I forgot to mention that. There is nothing in any source file that I defined as static (100%). I do have a parser.ypp and scanner.lex files that in turn create parser.tab.hpp\cpp and lex.yy.c, where there are static definitions, but those are created by bison and flex.

Comment: Well from the trace a `SymbolStack` is being constructed.  Put a breakpoint on the 1st line of the `SymbolStack` constructor before running the program.

Comment: Try breaking `pos_stack.push_back(pos_stack.back());` into two parts: `auto elem = pos_stack.back(); pos_stack.push_back(elem);` I think as written the call may exhibit undefined behavior: `push_back` takes its parameter by reference, and you are passing the reference to an element of that same vector, and the reference may become invalid when `push_back` reallocates.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik
I tried changing the code as you suggested but there is no change. The error occurs even is SymbolStack::push isn't called from the constructor, or for that matter even if the constructor is completely empty.

Comment: What's the stack trace in this case (say, when the constructor is completely empty)?

Comment: @RichardCritten
I tried putting a break point using the command: break parser.ypp:91 (the line we I call the constructor) but it simply doesn't stop.

Comment: Try `break SymbolStack::SymbolStack`. The `.ypp` file isn't directly compiled, it is first transformed into a `.cpp` file so your breakpoint is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> I didn't manage to debug it using gdb because it happens even before main is called.

1. GDB is *perfectly* capable of debugging crashes which happen before `main`.
2. You *show* GDB output (but your code is built without debugging (`-g`)).

> There is nothing in any source file I use that is defined as static.

You have a *global* `tables` variable. It is very likely that the crash is happening during that variable's initialization.

---

You should be able to debug this yourself by re-building with `-g` and setting a breakpoint on `SymbolStack::SymbolStack`.

The only thing I can think of is that if `T_VOID == T_NONE`, then this line:

```
    retType = retType == T_NONE? scope_stack.back()->ret_type : retType;
```

will use non-existent `scope_stack.back()` (`scope_stack` is still empty), and that should crash.

P.S. To understand the crash, it is often helpful to examine the crashing instruction (`(gdb) x/i $pc`) and register values (`(gdb) info regs`).